# How to pass a limit parameter to an include using Jekyll's Liquid

Tags: for-loop, include, jekyll, liquid

I have a collection of projects on my site that I iterate over using `{% for project in site.projects %}` and store in an include called `projects-list.html`.

I would like to include the latest project from this collection on the homepage as a ‘featured’ item – is it possible to include the `projects-list` but pass in a `limit:1` parameter so that only the first project is shown? Based on the Jekyll docs found here, I have tried passing the parameter to the include like this:

`{% for project in site.projects limit:{{ include.limit }} %}`

and refercing the include like this:

`{% include projects-list.html limit=1 %}`

but this does not appear to work. Is this a syntax error or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the **first**

```
{% assign projectFeatured = site.projects | first %}

{% for projects in site.projects %} 
  {% include projects-list.html %} 
{% endfor %}

{% for projects in projectFeatured %}
 {% include projects-list.html %}
{% endfor %}
```

Though I encourage you to add a `featured: True` in your post and do something like that:

```
{% if post.featured == true %}

 {% include post.html %}

 {% endif %}
```

https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/first/

Comment: but then i don't think there would be anything to iterate over?

Comment: If you limit to one project then there is no need to iterate. Just assigning a value with the first project in the list does the job

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem though because i'm trying to only have one include file -- if i use this method then i have to have a separate file for the featured item?

Comment: great, thank you! i've posted my solution above but i'm not sure it's very efficient. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Below is my current solution (with `featured: true`) added to post frontmatter. It's really nasty but appears to work for now:

```
<div class="project-list">
  {% if page.layout == "home" %}
    {% assign projects = site.projects | where: "featured", "true" %}
    {% for project in projects %}
      {% include project/project.html %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    {% assign projects = site.projects %}
    {% for project in projects %}
      {% include project/project.html %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</div>
```